# SP 2013 - Alert Notification - links to pdf files not opening

Tags: permissions, alert, pdf

We appear to have an issue where the link/icon to the document in the Alert Notification sent to users will not open a .pdf file. When the user clicks the icon/link they get a message saying that they don't have permission to access the file

It's not the site permissions (we hadn't changed these) and users are still able to open the same document using the standard site navigation

The problems appears to be specific to .pdf files

Is there a setting that constrains .pdf being used in Alert Notifications?? If so, how do I reset it so that users can open the file